# Using HashMap values of HashSet type

Tags: java, hashmap, hashset

I have some problem using HashMap values of HashSet type. I declared it as followed:

```
HashMap<Double, HashSet<Double>> pre = new HashMap<Double, HashSet<Double>>();
```

In my program I am generating pythagorean triples (a, b, c). I want to add b to the HashSet corresponding to the key a and add a to the HashSet corresponding to the key b.
There are 9 triples with perimeter less than 60:

```
3 4 5
6 8 10
9 12 15
12 16 20
15 20 25
5 12 13
10 24 26
7 24 25
15 8 17
```

So after generating each triple, I have to update the HashSet corresponding to a or b. After completion, the HashMap will look like followd:

```
1:                14:
2:                15: 8, 20
3: 4              16: 12
4: 3              17:
5: 12             18:
6: 8              19:
7: 24             20: 15
8: 6, 15          21:
9: 12             22:
10: 24            23:
11:               24: 7, 10
12: 5, 9, 16      25:
13:               26:
```

How can I do this? Any help will be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.math.*;

public class prob {
    public static double P = 60.0;
    public static double primCount = 0.0;
    public static double tripCount = 0.0;
    public static ArrayList<Triple> pt = new ArrayList<Triple>();
    public static HashMap<Double, HashSet<Double>> pre = new HashMap<Double, HashSet<Double>>();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        double sum = 0.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            pre.put((double)i, new HashSet<Double>(0));
        }
        p(3.0, 4.0, 5.0);
        for (int i = 0; i < pre.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(pre.get(i));
        }
        double end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Time elapsed : " + (end - start) / 1000d + " seconds");
    }

    public static void p(double A, double B, double C) {
        double a = A, b = B, c = C;
        if (a + b + c > P) {
            return;
        }
        primCount++;
        double I = Math.floor(P / (a + b + c));
        tripCount += I;
        for (double i = 1; i <= I; i++) {
            pt.add(new Triple(a * i, b * i, c * i));
            HashSet<Double> copya = pre.get(a * i);
            copya.add(b * i);
            pre.remove(a * i);
            pre.put(a * i, copya);
            HashSet<Double> copyb = pre.get(b * i);
            copyb.add(a * i);
            pre.remove(b * i);
            pre.put(b * i, copyb);
        }
        p(a - 2 * b + 2 * c, 2 * a - b + 2 * c, 2 * a - 2 * b + 3 * c);
        p(a + 2 * b + 2 * c, 2 * a + b + 2 * c, 2 * a + 2 * b + 3 * c);
        p(2 * b - a + 2 * c, b - 2 * a + 2 * c, 2 * b - 2 * a + 3 * c);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Jonatan Cloutier, I added my code.

Comment: I think your example output has an error: shouldn't it say `15: 8, 20` instead of just `15: 20`?

Comment: @Brian Rogers, you are right. I made a mistake. I did it manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your key is a double, but you get the value passing an int, just add the cast and it work for me:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < pre.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(pre.get((double)i));
    }
```

or using a foreach make it less error prone:

```
    for (Entry<Double, HashSet<Double>> entry : pre.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " : " + pre.values());
    }
```

Further more, when adding a value to a sub collection you don't need to overwrite it, just use it directly:

```
    pt.add(new Triple(a * i, b * i, c * i));
    pre.get(a * i).add(b * i);
    pre.get(b * i).add(a * i);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Such a small bug is difficult to notice.